# Adjust fixed element's bottom property according to width

Tags: html, css, height

How to adjust a fixed element's bottom property relative to screen-width?

```
#element {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: window.width * 0.5; /* ? */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use screen width you'll love vw instead of % what means 'Viewport width' or screen heigth as vh (viewport heigth)

Code will be
`bottom: 50vw`

My best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc() css propertie. http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1630-la-fonction-calc-en-css.html
Or just a percent http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp

Comment: how to use calc() in this specific situation?

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow CSS to adjust fixed element bottom property relative to screen-width

```
#element {
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use `%`** 
eg:`bottom:5%;
    width:100%;`
it will adjust with screen size

Comment: But in that case, it calculates 5% of the height not of the width which is the main problem.

Comment: set `width` and `height` properties then it wont affect its size